# 400 (bad request) on a curl request from a PHP script that worked on a linux terminal

Tags: php, linux, curl

So i have been writing a php script for a project that i am working on and have been testing it on my laptop by running it in the terminal (the os is Ubuntu 14.04).

Once i finally got the script to function as i wanted i uploaded it and when i tried to run it using Chrome this part started causing a 400 error (bad request) and i have no idea why. I also tested it in Edge and the same thing happened.

The urls passed to the setopt are the same as is the token and script.
I did use FileZilla and WinSCP to upload/download the file from my laptop to desktop maybe that has something to do with it?

any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
curl_setopt($cp,CURLOPT_URL,$url );
curl_setopt($cp,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-Y-Token:'.$TOKEN));
curl_setopt($cp, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($cp, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```

$url = "https://---------------.com/api/v1/4356/exports?search=".$searchId."";

^This is an example of the url

Comment: an example of the $url??

Comment: Thanks, first question, are you sure HTTPS is set up correctly on the new platform?

Comment: It seems to be but no I am not sure

Comment: telnet myserver https worked in the terminal

Comment: OK, easiest way to check is just to hit the https URL on it's own, so just hit:   https://---------------.com/. If you get a 200 then everything's OK and that's not the issue, if you get a 400 then you know HTTPS is probably the cause.

Comment: The url took me to the site whose api I am polling with no errors

Comment: I notice you're setting CURLOPT_POST, what is the post data you're sending? Could you update your question to include this?

Comment: I am not actually posting data using post with that url starts a search on their side which i later export with a get call.

Comment: that's odd because the search params are actually a GET request (they are in the URI) not a POST request. Try removing the line that sets CURLOPT_POST.

Comment: Yeah its odd but that is how their api works. Removing the post results in an invalid path result: {"error":"Your request path is invalid."}